# check if time in range between 12:00 am to 6:59 am

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

I using angular and ionic 4. I got issue to checking time range between 12:00 am to 6:59 am.

Example code as below

HTML

```
<ion-datetime[(ngModel)]="data.laterTime"
           (ionChange)="saveDate($event)" displayFormat="HH:mm" min="00:00"
           max="23:59" hourValues="00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23" minuteValues="0, 15, 30, 45"> </ion-datetime>
```

ts

```
saveDate($event) {

    if (moment($event.detail?.value).format('hh:mm a') <= '12:00 am' && moment($event.detail?.value).format('hh:mm a') < '07:00 am') {
       console.log("success!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: could you just convert the two to unix timestamps and check if the value is between the two?

Comment: you mean to convert like this `console.log(moment.unix($event.detail?.value).format('hh:mm a'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert each time strings to moment and compare it. Like this:

```
wrapIntoMoment(value: string) {
    return moment(value, 'h:mma');
  }

saveDate($event) {
  if (
    this.wrapIntoMoment($event.detail?.value) >=
      this.wrapIntoMoment('12:00 am') &&
    this.wrapIntoMoment($event.detail?.value) <
      this.wrapIntoMoment('06:59 am')
  ) {
    console.log('success!!!');
  }
}
```

There is an example for you with some test cases in constructor:
[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/moment-js?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)